# Why bookmark id changed after opening the document in Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I'm adding bookmarks to Word document using open XML SDK and I'am also setting the bookmark id and name programmatically, after opening the document in Word, I re-open the document as WordprocessingDocument and I find that the bookmark id was changed to values like 0,1,2..., I want to know why Word is modifying the bookmarks Ids, I still can use the name to find the bookmark instead of id since I use the same value for both id and name but this behavior looks strange for me.

Here is the code that I use :

```
BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = CreateBookmarkStart(entity.Id.ToString(), entity.Id);
        BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = CreateBookmarkEnd(entity.Id);
        Paragraph paragraph1 = CreateParagraph();
        body.Append(bookmarkStart1);
        body.Append(paragraph1);
        body.Append(bookmarkEnd1);


private static BookmarkStart CreateBookmarkStart(String name, long id)
    {
        return new BookmarkStart
        {
            Name = name,
            Id = id.ToString()
        };
    }

private static BookmarkEnd CreateBookmarkEnd(long id)
    {
        return new BookmarkEnd() { Id = id.ToString() };
    }
```

ids used are values like : 245103 , 39045 ...

Comment: It seems there is a problem with your code, but we can't help you if we don't know what your code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, you can (and should) be relying on the bookmark name, not ID.  Things like the REF field use name, not ID.

The ID seems to only be there to pair the bookmark start and end point tags.